# Consumindo um WEB API no Visual Studio

Tags: c#, xamarin

Eu criei uma WEB API em asp.net que está hospedada em um servidor web. Esta WEB API acessa uma tabela no SQL Server onde eu tenho uma tabela chamada Produtos com Id, nome, descrição e Preço, fiz os testes via POSTMAN e está funcionando corretamente, mas quando eu tento consumir o método para trazer um produto específico via aplicação xamarin no visual studio

Eu recebo o seguinte mensagem de erro no modo de interrupção

application in interrupt mode

Unhandled Exception:

> ```
> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>
> ```

Segue abaixo o meu código para trazer um produto especifico acessando a API no servidor

```
public class DataService
{
    public async Task<List<Produto>> GetProductAsync(string NomeProduto)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

            string url = "http://ProdutosAPI.servidor.com/api";

            try
            {
               var uri = url + "/" + NomeProduto.ToString();
               HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
               var ProdutoJsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
               var Produto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Produto>>(ProdutoJsonString);
               return Produto;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)

            {
                throw ex;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Primeiro traduza sua Pergunta para Português pois está no `stackoverflow em português`

Comment: show! Agora é só aguardar atá auguem te ajudar. Sucesso!!!

Comment: Qual versão do Visual Studio e qual é a versão do Xamarin?

Comment: Amigo, se no POSTMAN funciona e no seu dispositivo não, cheque as permissões de internet da aplicação. Fonte: [Permissões em Xamarin](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/permissions?tabs=vswin)

Comment: Olá,
Onde sua aplicação está rodando? Você deve verificar o acesso a API a partir do dispositivo que roda a aplicação. Tente acessar o endereço da API via navegador do aparelho / emulador e caso não consiga verifique as configurações de rede (firewall, proxy, topologia etc..) do seu serviço.

Comment: Visual studio 2017 - estou recebendo esta mensagem Unhandled Exception:

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request

Answer (score 1):

Luiz, apesar se ser uma API e está online, o servidor bloqueia as requisições vindas de fora por questões de segurança.

Para que que funcione em seu arquivo global.asa, tente por isso.

```
private void EnableCrossDmainAjaxCall()
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
                // HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, Accept");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }

        }

protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
            EnableCrossDmainAjaxCall();
        }
```

Se não funcionar, da uma lida nisso: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290053/setting-access-control-allow-origin-in-asp-net-mvc-simplest-possible-method