# Cors erro - Visual Studio .Net Web API React

Tags: .net, api, visual-studio, react

Tenho um projeto onde o back é em .net e o front em react.

Consigo fazer todas as operações do CRUD com postman, entretanto, no react recebo erro de cors.

Já entendo a causa do problema, mas não consigo encontrar a solução. Consultei diversos sites (lista ao final) seguindo a risca as orientações, mas sem sucesso.

Para me certificar que não há problema com o front, subi uma api com php, "resolvi o cors" e tudo funcionou bem. Tentei usar proxy no react e extensões no navegador onde "resolvem o cors", mas problema persiste com o .net.

Alguém poderia ajudar? Removi todo código que não funcionou em meus testes.

## setup.js

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using FAP.Models;

namespace FAP
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<FapContext>(options => options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

## Controller

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using FAP.Models;

namespace FAP.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SolucaoPadroesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly FapContext _context;

        public SolucaoPadroesController(FapContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/SolucaoPadroes
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<SolucaoPadrao>>> GetSolucaoPadrao()
        {
            return await _context.SolucaoPadrao.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/SolucaoPadroes/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<SolucaoPadrao>> GetSolucaoPadrao(int id)
        {
            var solucaoPadrao = await _context.SolucaoPadrao.FindAsync(id);

            if (solucaoPadrao == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return solucaoPadrao;
        }

        // PUT: api/SolucaoPadroes/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutSolucaoPadrao(int id, SolucaoPadrao solucaoPadrao)
        {
            if (id != solucaoPadrao.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(solucaoPadrao).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!SolucaoPadraoExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        // POST: api/SolucaoPadroes
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<SolucaoPadrao>> PostSolucaoPadrao(SolucaoPadrao solucaoPadrao)
        {
            _context.SolucaoPadrao.Add(solucaoPadrao);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetSolucaoPadrao", new { id = solucaoPadrao.Id }, solucaoPadrao);
        }

        // DELETE: api/SolucaoPadroes/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<SolucaoPadrao>> DeleteSolucaoPadrao(int id)
        {
            var solucaoPadrao = await _context.SolucaoPadrao.FindAsync(id);
            if (solucaoPadrao == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.SolucaoPadrao.Remove(solucaoPadrao);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return solucaoPadrao;
        }

        private bool SolucaoPadraoExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.SolucaoPadrao.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

- [Consumindo um WEB API no Visual Studio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/312131/consumindo-um-web-api-no-visual-studio)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290053/setting-access-control-allow-origin-in-asp-net-mvc-simplest-possible-method
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Controle_Acesso_CORS
- https://www.hexacta.com/2014/09/15/How-to-enable-CORS-on-your-Web-API
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware
- https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: Supostamente basta configurar conforme [neste link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware). Tente novamente e certifique-se que o endereço é exatamente igual ao do front, inclusive com o http ou HTTPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Entendendo CORS**

Isso aconteceu porque CORS é uma implementação de segurança do browser. É o browser quem bloqueia a requisição.

O server, nesse caso, tem apenas o papel de notificar, quando perguntado, se uma origem é permitida ou não.

Isso quer dizer que por mais que ele diga que não reconhece a origem, uma requisição server-to-server não é bloqueada. Inclusive a requisição que faz a consulta de CORS é uma requisição adicional que usa o método OPTIONS (monitore isso com o devtools).

**Solução**

Este é um startup.cs que habilita CORS.

Pontos de atenção:

- services.AddCors
- builder.WithOrigins
- app.UseCors

```cs
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com",
                                        "http://www.contoso.com");
                });
            });

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins); 

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
```

Link da Documentação
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Eu já havia tentado, mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Consegui, mas mexi em muita coisa. Agora vou remover o excesso e ver o que realmente fez funcionar. Achando, informo aqui.